# How to make customized button key bigger like iPhone button key while clicking

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uicontrolevents

While clicking, I want the big letter like in this picture.

[image: big letter while clicking]

How can I do this for my new button 'ក'? This is the code that I create button:

```
consonantButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[consonantButton setTitle:@"ក" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 consonantButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hanuman" size:30];
consonantButton.frame = CGRectMake(242.0, 328.0, 27.0, 42.0);
[consonantButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[consonantButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//  [consonantButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//  [consonantButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//  consonantButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);

[consonantButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButtonNormal-khmer"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//  [consonantButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButtonHighlighted-khmer"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


[consonantButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchConsonantButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

How to make the shape like this when clicking ? what is it called ?
This is the code that I did for action : 
    - (void) touchConsonantButton:(UIButton*)sender{
    // [self.target performSelector:consonantAction withObject:sender];
        consonantButton.frame = CGRectMake(242.0, 310.0, 54.0, 84.0);
         consonantButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hanuman" size:50];}

and this is the screen shot: (it doesn't disappear to default)

[image: while clicking]

Comment: How did you put this letter in the end? I remember I answered one of your questions yesterday.

Comment: before I don't add code or picture yet, so I ask 1 more time to make clear whether s.o have answer! I also ask you for giving me some code, so  I ask 1 more time! Sorry that I don't edit the old and make the new one !

Comment: this is code I did when we click button:                      - (void) touchConsonantButton:(UIButton*)sender{
//    [self.target performSelector:consonantAction withObject:sender];
    consonantButton.frame = CGRectMake(242.0, 310.0, 54.0, 84.0);
     consonantButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hanuman" size:50];
    if (onSetTextFieldCallBack!= nil) {
        
        
        NSMutableString *c = (NSMutableString *)[[(UIButton *)sender titleLabel] text];
        
        self.onSetTextFieldCallBack (c);
        
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two targets to your button:

```
[consonantButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpConsonantButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[consonantButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownConsonantButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownInside];
```

Now selectors are:

```
-(void)touchUpConsonantButton(id)sender
{
  UIButton *btnClicked = (UIButton *)sender;
  // your code here
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    btnClicked.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f);
  } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
  }];
}
```

---

```
-(void)touchDownConsonantButton(id)sender
{
  UIButton *btnDown = (UIButton *)sender;
   // your code here
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    btnDown.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
  }];
}
```